# how to get the full contents of a node using xpath & lxml?

Tags: python, html, lxml, xpath

I am using lxml's xpath function to retrieve parts of a webpage. I am trying to get contents of a `<font>` tag, which includes html tags of its own. If I use

```
//td[@valign="top"]/p[1]/font[@face="verdana" and @color="#ffffff" and @size="2"]
```

I get the right amount of nodes, but they are returned as lxml objects (`<Element font at 0x101fe5eb0>`).

If I use

```
//td[@valign="top"]/p[1]/font[@face="verdana" and @color="#ffffff" and @size="2"]/text()
```

I get exactly what I want, except that I don't get any of the HTML code which is contained within the `<font>` nodes.

If I use

```
//td[@valign="top"]/p[1]/font[@face="verdana" and @color="#ffffff" and @size="2"]/node()
```

if get a mixture of text and lxml elements! (e.g. `something something <Element a at 0x102ac2140> something`)

Is there anyway to use a pure XPath query to get the contents of the `<font>` nodes, or even to force lxml to return a string of the contents from the `.xpath()` method, rather than an lxml object?

Note that I'm returning a list of many nodes from the XPath query so the solution needs to support that.

just to clarify... i want to return `something something <a href="url">inside</a> something` from something like...

```
<font face="verdana" color="#ffffff" size="2"><a href="url">inside</a> something</font>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand -- is this close to what you are looking for?

```
import lxml.etree as le
import cStringIO
content='''\
<font face="verdana" color="#ffffff" size="2"><a href="url">inside</a> something</font>
'''
doc=le.parse(cStringIO.StringIO(content))

xpath='//font[@face="verdana" and @color="#ffffff" and @size="2"]/child::*'
x=doc.xpath(xpath)
print(map(le.tostring,x))
# ['<a href="url">inside</a> something']
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to use a pure XPath
>   query to get the contents of the
>   `<font>` nodes, or even to force lxml
>   to return a string of the contents
>   from the `.xpath()` method, rather
>   than an lxml object?
>
> Note that I'm returning a list of many
>   nodes from the XPath query so the
>   solution needs to support that.
>
> just to clarify... i want to return
>   something something `<a
>   href="url">inside</a> something` from
>   something like...
>
> ```
> <font face="verdana" color="#ffffff" size="2"><a
> ```
>
> href="url">inside something

**Short answer**: No.

**XPath doesn't work on "tags" but with *nodes***

The selected nodes are represented as instances of specific objects in the language that is hosting XPath.

In case you need the string representation of a particular node's markup, such objects typically support an `outerXML` property -- check the documentation of the hosting language (lxml in this case).

**As @Robert-Rossney pointed out in his comment:  lxml's `tostring()` method is equivalent to other environments' `outerXml` property**.

Comment: thanks, have altered the vocab in the question... lxml doesn't seem to support innerXML() or outerXML() :(

Comment: @significance: I also modified my answer: No, XPath doesn't represent the node markup in a string form.

Comment: lxml's `tostring()` method is equivalent to other environments' `outerXml` method.

Comment: @Robert-Rossney: Thanks, I added this information to the answer.