# proper xpath to roll up text of children

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

I'm parsing a page that has structure like this:

```
<pre class="asdf">content a</pre>
<pre class="asdf">content b</pre>

# returns
content a
content b
```

And I'm using the following XPath to get the content:
`"//pre[@class='asdf']/text()"`

It works well, except if there are any elements nested inside the `<pre>` tag, where it doesn't concatenate them:

```
<pre class="asdf">content <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"</a>a</a></pre>
<pre class="asdf">content b</pre>

# returns
content
content b
```

If I use this XPath, I get the output that follows.
`"//pre[@class='asdf']//text()"`

```
content
a
content b
```

I don't want either of those. I want to get all text inside a `<pre>`, even if it has children. I don't care if the tags are stripped or not- but I want it concatenated together.

How do I do this? I'm using `lxml.html.xpath` in python2, but I don't think it matters. [This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114900/659298) makes me think that maybe `child::` has something to do with my answer.

Here's some code that reproduces it.

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring("""
<pre class="asdf">content <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">a</a></pre>
<pre class="asdf">content b</pre>
""")
for row in tree.xpath("//*[@class='asdf']/text()"):
  print("row: ", row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) is what you should use:

> `.text_content():`
>   Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup.

```
for row in tree.xpath("//*[@class='asdf']"):
    print("row: ", row.text_content())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> 
>>> tree = html.fromstring("""
... <pre class="asdf">content <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">a</a></pre>
... <pre class="asdf">content b</pre>
... """)
>>> for row in tree.xpath("//*[@class='asdf']"):
...     print("row: ", row.text_content())
... 
('row: ', 'content a')
('row: ', 'content b')
```

Comment: you're entirely right. I was focused on the xpath. Glad I included a demo program rather than making this solely an xpath question!

Comment: @tedder42 thanks for the minimal sample to demonstrate the problem. It is a pleasure to answer clear and well-explained questions like this one.