# Xpath that returns the whole document in python

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to debug some inherited code.  So there is a line of code 
`elt = doc.xpath('body/div/pre[@id="bb flags"]')[0]`

I want to see what the entire document looks like at that point, rather than just a specific piece.  So what xpath should I insert there?
i.e.

```
elt_entire_document = doc.xpath(new xpath)
logging.info("The full document here is " + elt_entire_document.text)
```

Is this even possible with xpath, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: why do you have to use xpath to see what's there in the document. What's there in doc?

Comment: @supputuri  Why are you asking?  What does that have to do with my question?

Comment: I was asking what `doc` refers in your code, not the content of your doc.

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this, based on our comments :

```py
logging.info("The full document here is " + text)
```

Comment: Florian, thanks, but that gives me:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
If I then change it to 
        logging.warning('td145 doc.text = ' + str(doc.text))
I get 
doc.text = None
Which I know isn't correct as the whole document, as the xpath as it currently is does return something.

Comment: @Tharpa what library do you used?

Comment: My predecessor used etree.  doc = etree.HTML(txt).

I guess that indirectly answers my question.  If I print out txt in the calling method, I have my answer.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my anwser accordingly. but you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title seems to be asking about selecting a ***whole document***, yet your question body seems to be asking about displaying a selected node...

### Selecting the whole document via XPath

Selecting the ***whole document*** might mean any of the following:

- `/` selects the *root node* of XML document.
- `/*` selects the *document element* (aka the *root element*) of the XML document.
  (Its parent is the *root node*.)
- `string(/)` selects the [*string-value*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the XML document.

See also:

- [What is the difference between root node, root element and document element in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025654/what-is-the-difference-between-root-node-root-element-and-document-element-in-x)
- [How to pretty print XML from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16090869/290085)

---

### Python pretty print subtree

- [How to use lxml and python to pretty print a subtree of an xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55385465/290085)
- [how to get the full contents of a node using xpath & lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114731/290085)